# Customising ActiveAdmin CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activeadmin

I am using Activeadmin and would like to export the associated model values in the same CSV file. I am able to get the result but its not in a proper format.
I want all the question to be the column name and the answer for that to be displayed in the row. can anyone help me?

Papplication.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Papplication do
 csv do
  column "Questions" do |papp|
    @questions.map do |question|
      question.question_text
    end
  end
  column "Answers" do |papp|
    @questions = Question.where(:program_id=>papp.program_id)
    @answers = Answer.where(:question_id => @questions.ids,:startup_id => papp.startup_id)
    @questions.map do |question|
        Answer.where(:question_id => question.id, :startup_id => @startup.id).first.answer_text
    end
  end
end
```

[image: Downloaded csv looks this]

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: I might be able to help out, but I need to know a bit more: does the number of questions per Papplication vary? Is there a stable set of 5 questions per pApplcation? I am assuming the last as the questions are supposed to be in the column headers.

Comment: @Sjors Branderhost , yes the questions per papplication will vary. There is no stable set of 5  til might vary as per the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own csv generation code. Here is some scaffolding code to get you started:

```
sidebar :download_as_csv, :only => [:index] do
  a(href: download_as_csv_admin_papplications_path(params.slice(:scope, :filter))) do
    'Download as csv'
  end
end

collection_action :download_as_csv, :method => :get do
  # define your own headers
  csv_headers = ["Question 1", "Answer 1", "Question 2", "Answer 2"] # customize yourself
  rawcsv = CSV.generate(:col_sep => ",") do |csv|
    # here you could add headers
    # csv << csv_headers
    # scoped_collection is provided by activeadmin and takes into account the filtering and scoping of the current collection
    scoped_collection.each do |papplication|
      csv_row = []
      # Create a convenience method in the Papplication model that returns a hash of question_text to answer_text
      papplication.questions2answers_hash.each do |question, answer|
        csv_row << question
        csv_row << answer
      end
      csv << csv_row
    end
  end
  send_data(rawcsv, :type => 'text/csv charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%e-%H%M%S")) and return
end
```

Good luck!