# Dynamic column names on ActiveAdmin CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to achieve this:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  csv do
    # Column label generated from a resource attribute
    column(user.name) { |user| user.age }
  end
end

# Output.csv =>
# John Doe; Bill
# 18, 21
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The CSV would contain several rows, one row for each user. So I don't understand why you would use a column label based on a single user from the download. I do not think this is possible within AA.

Comment: In my case the models involved are questions and answers. I would like to have the question text as the column label and the answer texts as rows.

Comment: In that case I would write custom csv generation code. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118882/790737 for inspiration.